# Removing vote results in blinking triangle

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, ios-app

After removing an up or downvote the triangle flashes before it is removed. I'm using the iPad app with version 1.1.0.132.

[image]

Comment: True, not specific to iPad. (reproduced with iPhone 4S device as well)

Comment: Do you mean the triangle flashes its blue state on and off? Otherwise, there is a correct, disabled state (while the voting operation is taking place) in which the triangle shows a slightly dimmed color.

Comment: @ArieLitovsky I've attached a short screencast (with the iPhone this time, version 1.2.0.138). I mean the last flash which is making no sense in my eyes (or maybe I didn't get it correctly).

Comment: Neat screenshot, how did you do that? I couldn't find anything letting one record the iPhone screen. (except for some experimental app which required changing the time and even then never really worked)

Comment: @ShadowWizard The app is called [X-Mirage](http://x-mirage.com/x-mirage/). You start it on your Mac, connect the iPhone via AirPlay and start screen mirroring, which then can be recorded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was an interesting bug – the flashing was caused because, when a vote takes place, a realtime update goes off almost immediately after, trying to update the question score before the voting operation has finished taking place. The realtime update was using the vote state before the voting was complete, resulting is a quick flash of the opposite state.

This will be fixed in **beta version 1.2.0.140.**